# Primefaces tab view not rendering in a dialog box

Tags: jsf, primefaces, modal-dialog, tabview

I am very new to primefaces. I am trying to implement primefaces tab view in a dialog. But it renders only the first tab and does not show any other tabs. When I inspect the element I see all the other tabs code in there but they are all grayed out.

Index.xhtml

```
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/main.xhtml"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:form id="addressForm">
    <div align="center">
            <p:commandButton value="Edit" id="editInfo" onclick="PF('dlg').show();"
                 icon="ui-icon-pencil" />
            <p:dialog widgetVar="dlg" width="860" height="540" header="Information" maximizable="true" minimizable="true" showEffect="fade">                
                <ui:include src="editTabView.xhtml"/>
            </p:dialog>
    </div>
</h:form>
</ui:composition>
```

editTabView.xhtml

```
<ui:composition  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:b="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<p:tabView cache="true" id="tabView" scrollable="true">
    <p:tab id="localAddressTab" title="Local Address">
        <h:form id="localAddressForm">
           <h1>Testing</h1>
        </h:form>
    </p:tab>
    <p:tab id="permAddressTab" title="Permanent Address">
        <h:form id="permAddressForm">
           <h1>Testing</h1>
        </h:form>
    </p:tab>
    <p:tab id="mailAddressTab" title="Mailing Address">
        <h:form id="mailAddressForm">
           <h1>Testing</h1>
        </h:form>
    </p:tab>
</p:tabview>
</ui:composition>
```

I am not sure what I am missing. Can anyone please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the issue is that you have nested forms; delete forms into each `<p:tab>`. All data will be submitted by the `<h:form id="addressForm">`